# Digital Audio out

Tags: hardware

I have recently been trying to pipe spotify from an android device via a Cambridge Audio Dac Magic (USB, Toslink, SPDIF) into my home stereo system.

Basically I am trying to run Spotify Connect into my home stereo. The  current solutions are

1. Spend a lot of cash purchasing a spotify connect hifi component, there only appears to be one of these, and it is hugely expensive
2. Gramfon - cheap, but only has headphone jack output, and it seems to want to set up its own wifi hotspot
3. iDevice - with a dock, there is direct digital output! but since I don't own any, it would cost as much as 1
4. a tablet etc with an otg cable, plugged into the Dac Magic - this works, but I can't charge at the same time so it can't be a permanent solution.
5. Amazon Fire TV, the most promising solution so far, but it only works when plugged into a tv! (A port of android to this would be perfect, but it isn't quite there yet)

What I would really like to do is find *something* that runs android that has a direct digital audio output. That I can hide away behind the hifi and never think about again! I have tried running Android on the PCDuino v2, but it is Android 4.2 and it doesn't seem to pick up the Dac Magic (otherwise it would be a perfect solution)

I'm considering waiting for Win10 on the Raspberry Pi, but I would really like to come up with an Android solution

So if anyone knows of any sort of android device, or a device capable of running 4.4 or 5 that can be charged and have a USB connection

Comment: Regarding #4, there are USB OTG cables with a splitter for charging, such as this: [Amazon: Micro USB Host OTG Cable with Micro USB Power for Samsung i9100 i9300 i9220 i9250 by AtomicMarket](http://www.amazon.com/Micro-Cable-Power-Samsung-AtomicMarket/dp/B009YPYORM)

Comment: This is an option, but it seems very hit and miss about what devices it actually supports, most devices don't allow charging while an OTG cable is in use. - If I can't find a more promising solution, I'll likely pick one of these devices up and use that, but it feels like a hack! and I'm wondering if anyone here has a better solution...

Answer (score 0):

Its not really an answer! but I don't think this is actually possible via Android at the moment. So I'm posting this to help those that land here via googling!

I purchased a Panasonic SH-ALL1C which was more expensive than I'd wanted to pay (£200 GBP) but it sounds good, and works with Spotify well.